# Like Box no longer displays feed, one is working fine, others are failing, don't know why?

Tags: feed, facebook-likebox

I’m obviously doing something wrong but can’t figure out what? I have used the Facebook Like Box on www.apered.com on the about us tab and it’s fine, but on a clients site at www.arenamediation.co.uk the like box doesn’t display the content, and I’m having the same problem with another. The content doesn’t display when in the plug in set up.
The Arena Mediation Like Box was working, then stopped. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it's helpful to include code or examples that demonstrate your problem and a way for other users to reproduce the issue, if you could add that to your post that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook seems to be hiding posts that are older than 30 days, try creating a new post on the stream and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this, but the Like Box on www.apered.com is not 292 and works fine, the other I'm having a problem with (not live yet) is 300px wide and doesn't show the content.

Comment: Thanks for that, this may be the answer for Arena Mediations Like Box, but the new one I am trying to set up, has a couple of 'young' posts on the page but nothing shows in the like box, either when live or when being set up in Facebook. I'm going to give it another go now actually, my client has given me his details.